# tagging elements in a list and comparing them

Tags: java, list, data-structures, arraylist, hashmap

I have a list of items stored in "zombie". A system print of time would give me.

```
[<1.0, 3.0, 2.0>, <2.0, 5.0, 4.0>, <2.0, 4.0, 1.0>, <4.0, 7.0, 3.0>]
```

My question is how can i assign a label to each element in the list so that i can call them at ease `<age, height, weight>`

The ultimate idea of labeling is so that i can do a sorting for the "heaviest" zombie and store the result into a hashmap.

```
 public class zombieCalculator{

    double age;
    double weight;
    double height;  

        public static Map<Position, List<Position>> Random (List<Position> zombie) {

        System.out.println(time);

        }

       public zombieCalculator( double age, double weight, double height)
  {
      this.age= age;
      this.weight= weight;
      this.height = height;

  } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best choice would be to create a Class Zombie with this 3 Parameter age, height and fat.
You can then Create a Fat-Comparator-Class to sort the zombies according to the fat-parameter:

```
class FatZombieComparator implements Comparator<Zombie>{

     int compare(Zombie z1, Zombie z2){
       return z1.getFat() - z1.getFat();
     }
 }
```

now you can store your Zombies in a List and sort the list with a comparator:

```
List<Zombie> zombies = new ArrayList<Zombie>();
zombies.add(...);
Collections.sort(zombies, new FatZombieComparator())
```

you can create new comparatoclass for age or height

Comment: Hi @JohnnyAW, i don't really understand how the comparator works. I have edited my code with your suggestion of a (zombie class) and 3 parameter. Still a little confuse with the tagging part though.

Comment: To sort a list java need to know, how to compare 2 objects(zombies), the comparator object tell java by the compare-method how to compare 2 zombies. i actually dont really understand the tagging issue... You have zombie-objects, you can access age, fat and height by zombie.getAge(), zombie.getFat() and zombie.getHeight()

Comment: I see what you mean over there with regards to comparing 2 objects. The reason why i mentioned tagging is because the input would be just numeric numbers <3,2,4>. There is no indication which one would be the age, height, fat. - @johnnyAW

Comment: in this case you should create a list of Zombie-Objects from your input, something like new Zombie(3,2,4).  After assigning the values to the Object-parameters you can access it by get-methods

Answer (score 0):

You need a class for Zombi.

```
class Zombi{
    double age, height, fat;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "age: " + age + ", height: " + height + ", fat: " + fat;
    }
}
```

Change the map to

```
Map<Position, Zombi> map;
```